# Resque caching active record cal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, redis, resque

I have a simple resque job that accepts a model id, fetches it, and then calls a method on the fetched item.

```
class CupcakeWorker
  @queue = :cupcake_queue
  def self.perform(cupcake_id)
    @cupcake = Cupcake.find(cupcake_id)
    p @cupcake
  end
end
```

I queue it from Cupcake's model, after_commit using the 'enqueue' method

```
def bake
  Resque.enqueue(CupcakeWorker, self.id)
end
```

The job queues and executes correctly .  However if I modify the record's data in the database or through the UI and proceded to queue the job again the operation doesn't execute using the new values.

I can only get it to fetch the new values if I restart the resque worker process.  Is resque caching the object?  Is there a way to ensure it refetches from the database every time the worker is called?

#### Edit:

I even pulled the query logs... the commit happens before the select query which fetches the Cupcake..
So this is neither a race condition coz of the order, nor a caching problem as a query fetches it...
Am clueless guys.. what could it be?
**Btw am using the after_commit gem in rails 2.3.8 and redis n resque combo**

Comment: Something I don't understand is that you're calling Cupcake@bake from your worker, which queues the task again. Is that right?

Comment: sorry my mistake... its some function...i have edited it.. the point is am printing it and the updated_at points to the previously saved time and not the recent commit always..

Comment: @Hari That weird, I presume `bake` is called in `after_commit` block Also do u see [CACHE] like think in ur log when u do  `Cupcake.find(cupcake_id)` in resque Ideally Cache should never come in picture because resque is not a rails process after all

Comment: Ya, bake is called in after_commit.. i dont see any cache like thing, and every time a DB query goes in the SQL logs, and that happens after the update query which triggers the after_commit later... Still it is fetching the old object.. I totally dunno y and ya it is weird :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try and force resque hit the database with this code

```
ActiveRecord::Base.uncached do
  @cupcake = Cupcake.find(cupcake_id)
end
```

uncached is available in [2.3.8](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryCache/ClassMethods/uncached)

This should work, unless the problem is not really a caching issue. Let us know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into problem with exactly same symptoms

After digging deep i have found, the my problem was in named scopes

i have something like this in perform:

```
letter = Letter.to_process.first
```

and in model i have

```
scope :to_process, where("scheduled_at < ?", Time.now).where('finished_at IS NULL').order('scheduled_at')
```

which is wrong as it runs all the time with the same value of scheduled_at as in the first execution of the named scope

this was correct

```
scope :to_process, lambda { where("scheduled_at < ?", Time.now).where('finished_at IS NULL').order('scheduled_at') }
```

if this is not related by any means to your case - if the you have problem with just the plain find(id), try to add this

```
Cupcake.connection.clear_query_cache
```

at the end of your perform method